# ALM capabilities in Visual Studio using TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, alm

Please help me out in understanding the application life cycle management capabilities in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS)?
And how can these capabilities be useful in the projects in which we use TFS

Answer (score 3):

ALM include different aspects of your project :

> Communication : Based on Workitems (Task, Bug, issue , Test, etc..), favorite tool is Web Portal, you have also Add In Communication.
>
> Source Control (Shelveset, Changeset, Branching, etc.)
>
> Integration continuous : Build Automation (Based on Workflow Foundation )
>
> Test
>
> Deployment (For 2013 Microsoft buy new tool InRelease in order to maange releases)
>
> Reporting

Microsoft propose differents tools for each profil of project (Differents tools that you must knows in scope ALM Microsoft) :

- `Web Portal` : For Stack User, Product Owner, Project Mamanger, Developpers
- `Ms Project` : For manager (Planify)
- `Add in Excel` : For User, Product Owner,
- `Team Explorer` : Just for technical experts, developper, accessed with Visual Studio
- `Microsoft Test Manager` : For Testers, Developpers
- `In Release` : For Deployers, Managers

All theses tools use TFS Platform, datas are stored in Sql Server Databases, accessed by Web Services installed on IIS (When you setup product).

> I suggest you to know also `Extensibility Tools` (Power Tools; lot of products help you to increase productivity)

link : http://tfsprod.codeplex.com/

> You must also know different aspect such as Collection projects , Team Project, Security, Area, Alerts, Checkin Policy etc.

link :

setup : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631899.aspx

use : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh529827(v=vs.110).aspx

Actually we are on 2013 version.

Most important to know that we have two versions, local version that you must setup with different modes , and `Cloud Version` named `Team Foundation Service`

I `suggest you to install Cloud version`, it's free for small project (< 5 mmbers).

link to subscribe : http://www.visualstudio.com/fr-fr

Good luck , subject is very far and very interessant

Answer (score 0):

Other interesting links for TFS ALM:

You will have to select a process template when you create a team project. This is an important step as its very painful if you want to change it afterwards.

Work with team project artifacts, choose a process template : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400752.aspx

Agile Project Management using TFS 2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189203.aspx

What's new for Application Lifecycle Management in Visual Studio 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385832.aspx